# InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Python type numpy.int64 cannot be converted

Tags: python, mysql-workbench

i don't know where the problem is arising!can anybody help me?

cnx=mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='suraj1697',host='127.0.0.1',database='model')
mycursor=cnx.cursor()
sql="INSERT INTO model2 (length,host_length,path_length,fd_length,tld_length,count1,count2,count3,count4,count5,count6,count_http,count_https,count_www,count_digit,count_letter,count_dir,count_ip,count_short) VALUES(%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d)"
print(sql)
data=[]
for i in range(1, 32):

## mycursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE model')

```
mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE model2(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,lenght INT,host_length INT,path_length INT,fd_length INT,tld_length INT,count1 INT,count2 INT,count3 INT,count4 INT,count5 INT,count6 INT,count_http INT,count_https INT,count_www INT,count_digit INT,count_letter INT,count_dir INT,count_ip INT,count_short INT)")
#record=[int(urldata['url_length'][i]),int(urldata['hostname_length'][i]),int(urldata['path_length'][i]),int(urldata['fd_length'][i]),int(urldata['tld_length'][i]),int(urldata['count-'][i]),int(urldata['count@'][i]),int(urldata['count?'][i]),int(urldata['count%'][i]),int(urldata['count.'][i]),int(urldata['count='][i]),int(urldata['count-http'][i]),int(urldata['count-https'][i]),int(urldata['count-www'][i]),int(urldata['count-digits'][i]),int(urldata['count-letters'][i]),int(urldata['count_dir'][i]),int(urldata['use_of_ip'][i]),int(urldata['short_url'][i])]
record=[urldata['url_length'][i],urldata['hostname_length'][i], urldata['path_length'][i], urldata['fd_length'][i], urldata['tld_length'][i], urldata['count-'][i],urldata['count@'][i], urldata['count?'][i], urldata['count%'][i], urldata['count.'][i], urldata['count='][i], urldata['count-http'][i], urldata['count-https'][i],urldata['count-www'][i], urldata['count-digits'][i], urldata['count-letters'][i],urldata['count_dir'][i], urldata['use_of_ip'][i], urldata['short_url'][i]]
data.append(record)
```

print(data)
mycursor.executemany(sql,data)
cnx.commit()

Answer (score 0):

One of your input data is of type, numpy.int6. The simple solution would be to encapsulate the value within int(). The right way is to use the astype() method provided by numpy.

ex:

> variable.astype(int)